# Why does .accentColor work for .foregroundColor(_:) and not for foregroundStyle(_:) in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view, deprecated

Since `foregroundColor` will be/is now deprecated I was trying to use the recommended alternative `foregroundStyle` but when I try to pass `.accentColor` as a parameter it shows this error:

[image]

Why did it work for `foregroundColor`? and what would be the best way to use `.accentColor` now?

[image]

Thanks for any info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foregroundStyle` takes a [`ShepeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle) whereas `foregroundColor` takes a [`Color`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color). As you can see in the documentation, `ShapeStyle` indeed doesn't declare anything called `accentColor`, so you cannot pass `.accentColor`.

You *can* pass `Color.accentColor` though, because `Color` conforms to `ShapeStyle`. Note that `Color.accentColor` is different from `.accentColor` in this context. Without the `Color` prefix, Swift tries to find a `accentColor` in `ShapeStyle`, because that's what `foregroundStyle` takes. See also [Implicit Member Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Implicit-Member-Expression) from the language reference.

If you want to add `accentColor` to `ShapeStyle`, you can:

```
extension ShapeStyle where Self == Color {
    static var accentColor: Color { Color.accentColor }
}
```

But also consider using [`.tint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/tint), which *is* a member of `ShapeStyle`. Documentation says:

> You can set the tint color with the `tint(_:)` modifier. If no explicit tint is set, the tint is derived from the app’s accent color.

Since it says "derived from", presumably this `ShapeStyle` is not *exactly* `Color.accentColor` - SwiftUI might make slight changes to it in different contexts to make it better "fit" its surroundings.